# Mass of produced carbon dioxide

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am studying for a big test and I ran across something that I couldn't solve no matter how hard I tried. (reading through old tests)

**Burning ethanol produces carbon dioxide ($\ce{CO2}$) and water ($\ce{H2O}$).**

**a) Write down a balanced chemical equation that illustrates the complete burning of ethanol.**

**b) What is the mass of produced carbon dioxide ($\ce{CO2}$), when completely burning 575 liters of ethanol?**

**NTP conditions apply. Ethanols density is 0.8 g/cm³.**

**M<sub>C</sub> = 12 g/mol, M<sub>H</sub> = 1 g/mol, M<sub>O</sub> = 16 g/mol**

For the first part I came up with $\ce{C_2H_6O (l) + 3O2(g) --> 2CO_2 (g) + 3H2O (g)}$

Then I calculated that $M_\ce{CO_2}$ = 44 g/mol and $M_\ce{H_2O}$ = 18 g/mol

I also calculated that 575 liters of ethanol weighs 460 kg

I know that m = nM

However I am not sure what to do next.
I may also be using some weird terms here as this is my translation and I've never dealt with math/chemistry in English.

Answer (score 2):

Ethanol's molecular mass $M(\ce{C2H6O})=46\ \mathrm{g/mol}$

$$n=\frac mM,$$
so 
$$\frac{460\,000\ \mathrm g}{46\ \mathrm{g/mol}} = 10\,000\ \mathrm{mol}$$

So having 10 000 moles we can multiply that by the molecular mass of carbon dioxide and multiply again by two because there are two carbon dioxides.

$$10\,000\ \mathrm{mol}\times44\ \mathrm{g\ mol^{-1}}\times2=880\,000\ \mathrm g=880\ \mathrm{kg}$$

Answer (score -3):

1.u can easily analyse that 1mole of etanol produces 2 moles co2.
2.so first calculate M for ethanol=46g/mol.
3.m calculated by u for C2H5OH is 460000gm
4.so no of moles=m/M=460000/46=10000 moles.
5.now 1mole C2H5OH produces 2mole co2 so
using unitary method 10000 moles of C2H5OH will produce=10000×2 Co2 moles.
6.molecular mass of co2=44g/mol,20000 moles=20000×44=880000gm=880kg of co2 is ur ans.